# Comparator#comparing sort by the attribute of the class attribute

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

Let say I have a class ClassA, and it has ClassB as its attribute:

```
public ClassA
{
    private String attr;
    private ClassB classB;
}

public ClassB
{
    private String attr1;
    private int attr2;
}
```

From the class above, is it possible to sort the list of ClassA `List<ClassA> list` by attribute of ClassB using `Comparator`? It can be sort by the ClassA attribute easily by the code `Comparator.comparing(ClassA::getAttr)`, but what if I want to sort the list by the attribute in `ClassB`, let say the `attr2` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so,

```
List<ClassA> sortedList = list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getClassB().getAttr2()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Pass the comparing `Function` to the `Comparator` and it will create a new `stream` sorted according to the given `Comparator`. Then collect it into a `List`.

If you want to handle null values, it can be done like below.

```
final List<ClassA> sortedList = list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getClassB().getAttr1(), Comparator.nullsLast(String::compareTo))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Remember to handle `null` too.

Comment: I have updated the answer so that it handles `null` values.

Comment: @Jai since the OP did not say that elements or values can be `null`, there is no reason to clutter the code with possibly obsolete `null` checks.

Answer (score 3):

Just normal dot notation...

```
comparing(item -> item.getClassB().getAttr2());
```

... just be careful with nulls.  It will throw a NullPointerException if the classB attribute is null for your ClassA object.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
Comparator.comparing(item -> item.getClassB().getAttr2())
```